# Are there upgrades for an Acer 6930G?

Tags: laptop, upgrade

I actually own an Acer 6930g that runs Windows 8 with a SSD. It is powered by a Intel Centrino Duo T9600 (2.8Ghz) and a NVidia GeForce 9600M GS.

It's a five year old machine I bought for cheap thanks to a bargain, and it was one of the most powerfull at this time. Although it still is for common tasks, it is getting old and struggle to run recent games at its maximum resolution. I think about get a new one, but as stupid as it seems it turns out I am very attached to this laptop I find very special for the following reasons:

- Despite of its relatively low resolution (1366x768), I actually **love** its comfortable high quality bright screen.
- Its mechanic AZERTY keyboard is rock solid, very comfortable and keys are well organized. I cannot stand this new generation of flat keys.
- The bass enhanced sound speaker is just **awesome** at the point it competes easily with a casual stereo system.
- It plastic hull is strong and can withstand above average shocks due to children somewhat turbulent (who has grown since, fortunately).

So here is my question about it.

- Can I still improve the performances of this laptop ? Can I still upgrade both the CPU and the graphic ?

Comment: Your second question is off-topic for SuperUser, we do not allow shopping/product recommendations.  Sadly the answer to your first question is almost certainly "no" as very few laptops can be upgraded past replacing memory and hard disk.

Comment: Sorry, I just read the FAQ and I missed that part. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intel Centrino is

> Intel® Centrino® processor technology is the brand name for Intel's wireless mobile computing technology. The brand signifies Intel's technology for notebook computers. The technology is based on mobile processor microarchitecture, mainboard chipset, and wireless network capability.
>   ... [according to Intel](http://www.intel.com/support/notebook/centrino/sb/CS-022099.htm)

You don't have an Intel Centrino Duo T9600.  You have an [Intel Core 2 Duo T9600](http://ark.intel.com/products/35563/).  No, I'm not nitpicking.  You are asking about replacing the processor, and knowing what you have in there is important when you start looking for replacements.  Believe it.

There are multiple hurdles to replacing a **LAPTOP** processor.  The largest of which is whether the laptop manufacturer wrote a BIOS that will recognize the processor.  Why wouldn't they do that, when Desktop manufacturers are constantly releasing BIOS revisions that are only for increased processor support?  Economics.  Sounds conspiratorial or paranoid, but it isn't.  Laptop manufacturers make money by selling laptops.  If you can upgrade the hardware to something better, you aren't buying a new laptop and they aren't making their money.  To this end, while desktop manufacturers will list what new processors are supported in a BIOS revision, Laptop manufacturers won't.  You need to be prepared for that.

If you want to **RESEARCH**, then you start looking up other Acer laptops in that same series and family, to see what processors were used and if any of them are better.  Provided the laptop was made at the same time, and in the same model series, if it is a better processor (same socket, etc) then chances are you can upgrade to it.

At the very least, you are most likely safe within the same series of processor... IE within the [T9000 series of processors](http://ark.intel.com/products/series/33900), which would limit you to the [T9900 3.06 dual core](http://ark.intel.com/products/39312/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T9900-6M-Cache-3_06-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB).

As to the video card, I've seen video that demonstrates that the 6930G uses an MXM form factor video card, which means it can be replaced and upgraded.. specifically an MXM Type II.  You can get more information at [MXM Upgrade](http://www.mxm-upgrade.com/), a great site for information on this form factor as well as the ability to purchase some cards... however, nothing should stop you from searching Ebay as well.  What's the best card you can get for that?  I've no idea.  MXM, although a standardized form factor, still proves to be touchy.  For a related example, the ATI Radeon HD4670 worked, but with issues, in the Acer 6920G.  It was an MXM-II card, being used in an MXM slot on a system that accepted and worked with MXM-II cards, yet it would not work properly.  Once you find a card or two you like... or if you just feel like getting specific recommendations, you should contact the people behind the site MXM Upgrade.

That covers the scope of your question that can be answered here.  Shopping recommendations are off-topic and will get your question closed.

Comment: +1, Thanks a lot for both your response and your edit. I am not sure I will get q better answer for this, so I mark it as accepted. I will try to get some prices and benchmarks based on your recommendations to check how such an upgrade worth it. If it is not the case, I hope I will manage to find an equivalent model from Acer (that never disappointed me). Too bad that SuperUser does not allow shopping recommendations.

Comment: I have to assume it is all about making sure the answers are generic enough to fit multiple situations.  Links to products where they are sold can and will eventually result in a 404 or a *discontinued* notification, making that information less useful.  That, and a shopping recommendation is only useful to one person really.  However... I can say that you should look for an NVidia 9800, or an ADI Radeon HD 3000 series card... you'll probably have the best luck with those.

Comment: Upgrading the graphic card sounds not that hard and I can do it myself: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdKz53tBmUY. But changing the CPU needs soldering. Ouch... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsW1DURTHco

Comment: No,it doesn't.  I looked up replacement motherboards for that model, and every one had a CPU socket, as in you lift a lever, and just lift the processor out of the socket.

Comment: Studid I am... This is not a CPU the guy is soldering. Thank you for rectification.

Comment: At 6:35 in the second video there, you can see after he removes the heat sink assembly, the CPU is in the middle of the motherboard, in a socket.

Comment: Here is cool upgrade guide for the beast : http://forum.notebookreview.com/acer/503155-my-aspire-6930g-upgrade-adventure-tutorials-how-tos-softwares-much-more.html

Comment: YAY! https://www.facebook.com/groups/Acer.Aspire.6930